# Inject HTML source into an iframe to avoid cross site scripting issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, web

I am trying to specify the source of an iframe to a blank HTML page. As the source is located on a different domain, I am getting 'Permission denied' error. Is there a way for me to inject the HTML source into the iframe to avoid the cross site issue?

Comment: I think this falls under cross-site scripting, so no this is not possible. If you have control of the site loaded in the iframe, you can perhaps use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage). May I ask what your end-goal is? Perhaps there's another way of doing whatever it is you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having an iframe to another domain usually isn't a problem,  you can prevent other's from viewing your site in an iframe by setting the x-frame-options's http header. (And i take you didn't bother to check the http response header...).

If you just need a blank page,  then open the iframe to a page you control.  like blank.html located in your doc root.

Comment: Thanks, we just created a dummy page on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

As Rook said, there usually isn't an issue with pointing an iframe cross site.  In fact, the iframe is one of the known ways to get around some level of cross site communication.  Furthermore, this mechanism is used in advertising to dynamically feed content to users on various websites.

Anyways, another way you can achieve what you want is to create a proxy service.  On your local server, you can write a script that makes a GET request for the page and then spit back out the HTML as its own response.  That way, your iframe's source can be pointing to your local server.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I will try to elaborate the problem in more detail. We are trying to separate the Javascript code on a web application by making them generic widgets. In order to provide flexibility for the widgets to be re-used by other applications, we can't take the proxy approach. That would require all the users of the widget to setup the proxy. We need to have all the Javascript under one domain. As the webpage is being rendered in a different domain, setting the iframe source in the widget to an HTML page on the javascript domain is causing problems.